# How to fix empty __dummy__ problem on desktop - ubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu

I'm using ubuntu 16.04. After I restart or log on ubuntu. The **dummy** file appear on desktop, but when I open to show the problem, unfortunately it's empty. I can not find cause to create the file. Could someone help me to detect and resolved this problem. Thanks

Comment: My best advice is to ignore the dummy file.

Comment: But, I feels uncomfortable when i saw it :)) @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to delete it in the GUI, the prompt said 'No such file or directory'.

So ran this in the problematic directory and worked well.

```
$ mkdir __dummy__
$ rm -r __dummy__
```

Answer (score 0):

- Open the file with any text editor(Like gedit)
- Write some text and save it.
- Now you can delete it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>
  It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I just had this and was able to delete it using the command line - navigate to the directory and run

$ sudo rm- rf _ *dummy* _

Comment: a) your comment has syntax errors(hyphens, spaces in the wrong place). It should be `sudo rm -rf __dummy__` b) even with correct syntax this didn't remove it for me