# Mysterious __dummy__ file appeared in my Downloads folder

Tags: 18.04, gnome, nautilus, files, services

While unpacking the zip file I got from the Internet (which I had prepared myself before on the other machine I owe) a Mysterious `__dummy__` file appeared in my Download folder for a brief moment. It disappeared quite quickly so I could not make any further investigation of it.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to replicate this issue. I have looked over Internet and have not found any information about that `__dummy__` file on ubuntu/linux. The only reference I found was this question on AskUbuntu. However it does not provide any information what the file is:
[How to fix empty __dummy__ problem on desktop - ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017795/how-to-fix-empty-dummy-problem-on-desktop-ubuntu-16-04)

I am wondering what was that file? What was it purpose and should I be worried?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, it's easy.

Rerun the extraction under `strace` (read `man strace`)

```
 strace -e trace=file unzip "the zip file" |& tee strace.log
```

This will show all the "file" operations, including the creation of your `dummy` file.

Comment: I will try that! However I am not sure if unziping the file was a true trigger of that event. It might have been just a coincidence. I need to pinpoint that the name of the dummy file was exactly that: `__dummy__`

Comment: I run provided by you command on my zip file. Unfortunately there is no trace of my mysterious `__dummy__` file in resulting output or in log. I start to think that the zip file is not directly connected with the issue. Does Ubuntu create `__dummy__`  files as part of some normal operation process? I checked my system with ClamAV just in case and I am pretty sure that it is clear from any malware.